# Multiple JLables into a single addMouseListener

Tags: java, jlabel

I got a 3 `JLable`s, and I added a functionality to `l3` of when is clicked, Set the `JLabel` text into a value store into an array (ans.get(0,0))

```
JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Obtener x1");

JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Obtener x2");

JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Obtener x3");
l3.setBounds(30, 180, 100, 25);
l3.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
  {
  l3.setText("X1 = "+ ans.get(0, 0));
  }
  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
  //MouseEntered, MousePressed, MouseRelease overriden methods....
```

The question here is, Is posible implementent The rest of `JLabel`s (`l1`, `l2`) into a single `addMouseListener` (same mouseListener belonging to a `JLabel` `l3`) ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a local variable for `MouseListener` and assign your instance to it. Then add the `MouseListener` to your each `JLable`s.

```
JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Obtener x1");
JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Obtener x2");
JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Obtener x3");

MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {...}

l1.addMouseListener(ml);
l2.addMouseListener(ml);
l3.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Then each `JLable` will share the same `MouseListener` object.